# Python- Adding a specified width to strings

Tags: python, file, word-wrap

I want to write a string to a file but I want to have a specified length, for example, in the text file, I want to write "Atom", I want it to have a specified length from column 1 - 6, and the next phrase/word, from column 7-11, next from 13-16, and etc... I would want to write to a text file say, random_text.txt, please help.

Thanks!

Basically, why I need it:

```
Column 1-6 Record Name
Column 7-11 Serial Number
Column 13-16 ATOM name/Type
Column 17 Alternate Location Indicator
Column 18-20 Residue Name
Column 22 Chainidentifier 
Column 23-26 Residue sequence number
Column 27 Code for insertion fo residues
Column 31-38 X-value
Column 39-46 Y-value
Column 47-54 Z-Value
Column 55-60 Occupency
Column 61-66 Temperature (Default 0.0)
Column 73-76 Segment identifier
Column 77-78 Element Symbol
Column 79-80 Charge on atom
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like [textwrap](http://docs.python.org/library/textwrap.html)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Python2.6 or later, you could use the [str.format](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) method:

```
with open('random_text.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('{0:6}{1:6}{2:4}'.format('Atom','word','next'))
```

yields a file `random_text.txt` with contents

```
Atom  word  next
```

The number following the colon indicate the width. For example, `{0:6}` formats the 0-th argument, `'Atom'`, into a string with a width of 6. The string could be "right-justified" by using the format `{0:>6}`, and there are [other options as well](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax).

Comment: how would you do it so atom has width of 1-6 columns, word is from 7-11, and next is from 13-16?

Comment: By specifying the width, you can indirectly arrange where the next column begins. For example, by specifying `col[0]` has width 6, the next column will begin at position 7. However, you must be careful that `len(col[0])<=6`, for otherwise the formatted string will run over into the next column.

Answer (score 5):

```
string = "atom"
width = 6
field = "{0:<{1}}".format(string[:width], width)
```

This will truncate `string` to `width` if necessary, since you can't actually specify the max width in format string, just the minimum width that the field will be padded to.

Answer (score 5):

Use [str.format](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax), define field widths (`:<width>`) and expand your data (`*<list>`).

```
>>> columns = ['aaaa', 'bbbbbb', 'ccc']
>>> print '{:4}{:6}{:3}'.format(*columns)
```

Additionally, you can abuse the precision `.8` to trim a string field. The first 8 sets the minimum field width.

```
>>> print '{:8.8}'.format('Too long for this field')
Too long
```

Comment: YAY for abuse! Very clean and simple.