# Python-Sorting strings to columns

Tags: python, file, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python- Adding a specified width to strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8459364/python-adding-a-specified-width-to-strings)

Sort strings by their width, for example the instructions below, I have specific values for each column shown below, however I want to then print out the values (after being generated) into this format into a text file.

```
Column 1-6 Record Name
Column 7-11 Serial Number
Column 13-16 ATOM name/Type
Column 17 Alternate Location Indicator
Column 18-20 Residue Name
Column 22 Chainidentifier 
Column 23-26 Residue sequence number
Column 27 Code for insertion fo residues
Column 31-38 X-value
Column 39-46 Y-value
Column 47-54 Z-Value
Column 55-60 Occupency
Column 61-66 Temperature (Default 0.0)
Column 73-76 Segment identifier
Column 77-78 Element Symbol
Column 79-80 Charge on atom
```

output

```
ATOM      1  P    DG S   1       3.168  -8.339   4.060  1.00  0.00           P
```

Notice: Atom is Column 1-6, 1 is column 7-11, etc...

THanks!

Comment: What is the question? Can you give a shorter example, provide example input and say what the output should be?

Answer (score 4):

To sort a list of strings by their *Residue Name*, use something like this:

```
list_of_strings.sort(key=lambda s: s[17:20])
```

To learn more about sorting techniques, see [Python's Sorting HOWTO Guide](http://docs.python.org/howto/sorting.html).

To learn more about string slicing see the [Python Tutorial Section on Strings](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#strings).

To build-up strings with this record layout, use [fixed-width string formatting](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations).  For example:

```
>>> '%-6s%5s%4s' % ('ATOM', 1, 'P')
'ATOM      1   P'
```